# Filter models with pivot table extra field value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i have three tables

```
tours (id , body) -> assume a record is (id: 1, body: somethings)

metas (id , key)-> assume a record is (id: 1, key: tour_price)

metables (meta_id , metable_id, metable_type, value) -> assume a record is: (meta_id: 1, metable_id: 1 , metable_type: App\Tour , value : 250000)
```

i want filter results with meta value like this :

```
where tour_price is 250000 ?
```

also my Tour model has function like this :

```
public function metas()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Meta', 'metable')->withPivot('value');
}
```

i tried this :

```
$tours = Tour::whereHas('metas', function($q){
    $q->where('key','tour_price');
})->get()
```

it just return tours with tour_price key in pivot table. i want something like this :

```
$tours = Tour::whereHas('metas', function($q){
    $q->where('key.tour_price','250000');
})->get()
```

but it did not work .

my tables structure :

metas :
[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVMKU.jpg)

metables :

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4tc6.jpg)

Comment: why have you created polymorphic relation ? i think it should be ManyToMany relation between `tours` and `metas`

Comment: i want use metas for other models in my application. for that reason i added polymorphic relation. it's wrong ? can in use polymorphic ManyToMany relation same as simple ManyToMany relation in laravel ?

Comment: did you try `$q->where('key','tour_price')->wherePivot('value', 250000);` ?

Comment: yes, it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it !
solution is:

`$q->where('key','tour_price')->where('value', 250000);`

and if you want use multiple condition, you can try :

```
Tour::whereHas('locations', function($q){
        $q->where('slug','=','istanbul');
    })
        ->whereHas('metas', function($q){
            $q->where('key','tour_start_date')
                ->where('value','>=', '2018-07-23 00:00:00');
        })
        ->whereHas('metas', function($q){
            $q->where('key','tour_end_date')
                ->where('value','2018-08-05 00:00:00');
        })->get();
```